# jQuery mask inside AngularJS modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, mask

I am using a jQuery mask outside my [modal](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) scope, like this:

```
$("#input").mask("(00) 00000-0000");
```

When I try to use this inside my modal controller, it doesn't works.

Someone has an explanation for that?

**Code of controller:**

```
$scope.modal = function (cl) {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        inputs: {
            x: x
        },
        controller: function ($scope, close, x) {

            $("#input2").mask("(00) 00000-0000");

            $scope.close = function (op) {
                //doSomething...
            };
        },
        controllerAs: "ModalController"
    }).then(function (modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function (result) {
            //doSomething...
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: plugins should be initialized in directives

Comment: @charlietfl how could I do that?

Comment: do a search for "angular jquery plugin directive" or similar...should find lots of results

Comment: Mixing jQuery and AngularJS like this is asking for trouble. Consider using [UI-MASK](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask).

Comment: We get a ton of these, AngularJS + jQuery = issue. The two frameworks aren't in sync.

Comment: @charlietfl In this case, simply invoking the jQuery plugin from a directive won't work. The event handlers used by the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) will fight the event handlers added by the jQuery plugin.

Comment: @georgeawg agree. Was trying to steer rather than give absolute answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [UI-MASK](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask)

```js
angular.module("app",['ui.mask'])
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <input type="text" ng-model="phonenumber"
           ui-mask="(99) 99999-9999"  ui-mask-placeholder 
           ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" />
    <br>
    Number= {{phonenumber}}
  </body>
```